# Creating a 5x5 Matrix with number 1 in the middle

Tags: matlab

I need to create a 5x5 matrix with the number 1 in the middle.  I'm not allowed to explicitly enter in the elements.

I'm currently using this,

```
repmat(eye(5),1)
```

**To Give**

```
 1     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0     1
```

How can I get rid of the one's that aren't in the middle?

Comment: How about `full(sparse(3, 3, 1, 5, 5))`?

Comment: This is silly but you could do: `x = subsasgn(zeros(5), substruct('()',{3 3}), 1)`

Answer (score 6):

yet another one liner:

```
padarray(1,[2 2])
```

Comment: Yet another Matlab function I didn't know it existed... :-)

Answer (score 4):

Although I don't get the point of this question, there are many options, and it's fun to think of weird ones :-)

- Multiply element-wise by rotated matrix: `A = eye(5);  A = A.*rot90(A)`
- Multiply element-wise by flipped matrix: `A = eye(5);  A = A.*flipud(A)`
- `A = A + flipud(A); A = A==max(A(:))`
- `A = zeros(5); ind = ceil(numel(A)/2); A(ind) = ~A(ind)`
- `A = magic(5); A = A==sum(A(:,1))/size(A,1)`

Comment: +1, I would like to add this one: A = zeros(5); A(round(end/2)) = 1;

Comment: @RobertP That's a good one too. However, since the OP said "I'm not allowed to explicitly enter in the elements", I would replace your `A(round(end/2)) = 1` by `A(round(end/2)) = ~A(round(end/2))` for example

Answer (score 4):

Adding to [Luis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18939877/1714410), a way to abuse the image processing toolbox:

```
>> fspecial('gauss',[5 5], eps)
```

I'll bet [Gauss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss) wouldn't have liked that...

You can use linear indexing as well

```
>> A = reshape( 1:25, [5 5] ) == 13;
```

Comment: Well thought. And this has given me another idea: sinc funtion :-)